# Can you programmatically call upon a specific case in a switch-case?

Tags: objective-c, c, switch-statement

I have a switch case that looks like this:

```
switch ( class.Function() )
{

    case firstThing:
    {

    }
        break;
    case secondThing:
    {
     //call third thing
     }
     break;
    case thirdThing:
    {

     }
     break;

    }
```

Is there any way to call a specific case in C / Objective-C?

Comment: sure, make sure `class.Function()` always returns the corresponding case value.

Comment: You should clarify what you are trying to accomplish here. Using a `switch` statement as you describe makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you would want to do that, but in your example, if you simply leave out the break statement at the end of case secondThing: the user will continue through the subsequent case statement until they hit a break.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you're trying to implement is switch statement fall through. By leaving out the break statement after case #2, you will execute whatever code is in case #3. This may be what you want.

```
switch ( class.Function() )
{

    case firstThing:
    {

    }
        break;
    case secondThing:
    {
     //go to case 3
    }

    case thirdThing:
    {

    }
     break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, you could use case fall through, but that is not a solution to your question in general, and if there is code specific to `secondThing`, it can lead to confusion and could be considered bad practice.

```
switch ( class.Function() )
{
    case firstThing:
    {

    }
    break;

    case secondThing:
    case thirdThing:
    {

    }
    break;
}
```

If you simply implement the body of each case as a function, then that is perhaps the more general solution:

```
switch( class.Function() )
{
    case firstThing:  something();                     break;
    case secondThing: anotherThing(); oneMoreThing();  break;
    case thirdThing:  oneMoreThing();                  break;
}
```